# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down at

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

While downloading file from S3 it is failing and giving me this exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
>
> at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:251)
>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>      at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
>     at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy70.requestConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1190)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4221)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4168)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1249)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.doDownload(TransferManager.java:1053)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.doDownload(TransferManager.java:1007)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.download(TransferManager.java:845)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.download(TransferManager.java:801)
>     at
>   com.capitalone.homeloans.imaging.common.s3communicator.AsyncS3Manager.lambda$download$0(AsyncS3Manager.java:82)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please include the code you are using for the download

Answer (score 0):

in the databricks runtime environment, i found success using the solution from this article mixed with a small variation on the prefix for the configuration key:

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum 3`

the original article solution said to use:

`fs.s3a.connection.maximum`

https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/jobs/job-fails-connection-pool

Comment: technically this didn't *completely* solve my issue, but at the very least, none of the traceback contains S3-related errors anymore :)

Answer (score -1):

Do not close your client after a request if you are pooling the connections.

That is, you are probably doing something like this:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
...
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
     .setConnectionManager(pool)
     .build();

try { // try-with-resources
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
             InputStream fis = response.getEntity().getContent();
            ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(fis)) {
             // ... get data ...
     } finally {
         httpclient.close(); <====== !!
     }
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    // exception handling ...
}
```

That `httpclient.close()` is causing your next pooled connection to fail.

---

<sup>Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033548/1329340</sup>

Comment: this explains nothing about the issue as the question was specifically related to an api call withing the aws s3 java sdk. sure sounds great, but why would a commercially provided api after millions of successful requests suddenly start spitting out this error?